# Forgot Apple Password

Tags: iphone, recovery, unlock

My iPhone is "Locked to owner". I bought this phone brand new from store. It's been over a week, still no call nor wait time. No email with information sent.
Apple Support nor Apple store can't help with this process,
I need contact information for the Recovery department to  help me straighten this out.I  don't k how what to do

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question to be answered. It's just a rant.

Comment: Who is the previous owner? They need to remove the activation lock of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

We are not Apple so all we can offer are recommendations on how to proceed.

I assume that the owner the phone is locked to is not you. So the options you have are

- Take the phone back to the store you bought it from and request either a replacement or your money back (because you obviously can't use the phone)
- Take the phone to an Apple Store together with proof of purchase and have it unlocked.